# Multiline search in txt file with python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, multiline

I have txt with patterns like this:

```
...
72 anything
73 }
74 something {
75 something2
76 something3 withVariableTextHere
77 anything
...
```

I've tried searching for: `"something {\nsomething2\nsomething3)"` and I do get True result with re.findall, but after I've found the pattern I want to print whole #76 line, because I need info after "something3".

Does anyone have idea how I could do that? And I want to do it multiple times trough the same file, essentially whenever pattern is found I want to print whole third line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capturing groups in your regex. For example:

```
s = """anything
}
something {
something2
something3 withVariableTextHere
anything"""

re.findall("something {\nsomething2\nsomething3(.*)", s)
```

Will yield:

```
[' withVariableTextHere']
```

In short, it will return everything that matches the part of the regex in parenthesis, here *anything before a new line*.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Derlin, that was what I was looking for. After couple of days trying to do this you really saved me :)